# Draw arc on mousemove event using Kineticjs

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I have to draw an arc on the layer on mousemove event as per requirement. How can be the parameters in the function `context.arc(x,y,startAngel,endAngle,Counterclockwise)` fixed according to current mouseposition? My code is as following :

```
var newarc;
ui.stage.on("mousedown", function () {
    var arc = new Kinetic.Shape({
        drawFunc: function (canvas) {
            var context = canvas.getContext();
            var pos = ui.stage.getMousePosition();

            var sx = Math.floor(pos.x / ui.scale - ui.stage.getAbsolutePosition().x / ui.scale + ui.stage.getOffset().x);
            var sy = Math.floor(pos.y / ui.scale - ui.stage.getAbsolutePosition().y / ui.scale + ui.stage.getOffset().y);
            var x = sx;
            var y = sy;
            var radius = 100;
            var startAngle = 1 * Math.PI;
            var endAngle = 0.5 * Math.PI;
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
            canvas.stroke(this);
        },
        fill: '#00D2FF',
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        // draggable: false
    });
    newarc = arc;
    moving = true;
    ui.myLayer.add(newarc );
});

ui.stage.on("mouseup", function () {
    moving = false;
})

ui.stage.on("mousemove", function () {
    if (!moving) {
        return;
    }

    var dx = x - startX;
    var dy = y - startY
    var aradius = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
    newarc.radius = aradius;
    ui.myLayer.drawScene();
    ui.myLayer.add(newarc);
    ui.stage.add(ui.myLayer);
});
```

Comment: I'm not understanding...what do you want to happen as the user moves their mouse?

Comment: @markE: simply as the user moves mouse in any direction, the arc should be drawn on that path

Comment: Need more info...But the user may not draw an arc path.  What happens if they draw a straight line?

Comment: @markE: I have distinct select options and draw functions  for all shapes, if the user select arc, the corresponding drawArc func will be called. The code above is part of that function.

Comment: [Frustrated...] Yes, I see that.  But is this what you want to happen?  (1) on mousedown a new arc is created with its center on the mouseposition (2) on mousemove the arc radius changes to be equal to the distance from the arc center to the current mouse position.  If so, use newarc.setRadius(aradius). Some observations: (A) You're forgetting to get the x,y in mousemove.  (B) You're trying to add the same "newarc" to myLayer (but newarc is already on myLayer.)

Comment: [Sorry....]Exactly i need the scenario as u have mentioned. I have almost an arc drawn but mousemove event is not working fine. on mousemove what should be the start and new value of (1) x , y & radius (2)startAngle and endAngle.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how to create a circle by dragging the mouse.**

Mousedown:

- Create a new circle with its center at the mouse position.

Mousemove:

- Change the radius of the circle to the distance between center-circle and the mouse.

Mouseup:

- End resizing the circle

[image]

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/NQDdE/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var newArc;
    var isDown=false;

    stage.on("contentMousedown",function(){
        var mouse=stage.getMousePosition();
        newArc=new Kinetic.Circle({
            x:mouse.x,
            y:mouse.y,
            radius:.25,
            fill:randomColor(),
            stroke:"lightgray",
            strokeWidth:3
        });
        layer.add(newArc);
        layer.draw();
        isDown=true;
    });

    stage.on("contentMousemove",function(){
        if(!isDown){return;}
        var mouse=stage.getMousePosition();
        var dx=mouse.x-newArc.getX();
        var dy=mouse.y-newArc.getY();
        var radius=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
        newArc.setRadius(radius);
        layer.draw();
    });


    $(stage.getContent()).on('mouseup', function () {
        isDown=false;
        newArc=null;
    });



    function randomColor(){ 
        return('#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
    }

    layer.draw();



}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```